# Creating tensors on M1 GPU by default on PyTorch using jupyter

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Right now, if I want to create a tensor on gpu, I have to do it manually. For context, I'm sure that GPU support is available since

```
print(torch.backends.mps.is_available())# this ensures that the current current PyTorch installation was built with MPS activated.
print(torch.backends.mps.is_built())
```

returns True.

I've been doing this every time:

```
device = torch.device("mps")
a = torch.randn((), device=device, dtype=dtype)
```

Is there a way to specify, for a jupyter notebook, that all my tensors are supposed to be run on the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The convenient way**

There is no convenient way to set default device to MPS as of 2022-12-22, per discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/82296).

---

**The inconvenient way**

You can accomplish the objective of 'I don't want to specify `device=` for tensor constructors, just use MPS' by intercepting calls to [tensor constructors](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/82296#issuecomment-1198613567):

```py
class MPSMode(torch.overrides.TorchFunctionMode):
    def __init__(self):
        # incomplete list; see link above for the full list
        self.constructors = {getattr(torch, x) for x in "empty ones arange eye full fill linspace rand randn randint randperm range zeros tensor as_tensor".split()}
    def __torch_function__(self, func, types, args=(), kwargs=None):
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        if func in self.constructors:
            if 'device' not in kwargs:
                kwargs['device'] = 'mps'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

# sensible usage
with MPSMode():
    print(torch.empty(1).device) # prints mps:0

# sneaky usage
MPSMode().__enter__()
print(torch.empty(1).device) # prints mps:0
```

---

**The recommended way:**

I would lean towards just putting your device in a config at the top of your notebook and using it explicitly:

```py
class Conf: dev = torch.device("mps")
# ...
a = torch.randn(1, device=Conf.dev)
```

This requires you to type `device=Conf.dev` throughout the code. But you can easily switch your code to different devices, and you don't have any implicit global state to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

as of 2023-01-20, with pytorch 2.0 nightly, you can set default device as mps using:

```py
torch.set_default_device("mps")
```

Answer (score 0):

As of torch 2.0, you can do this:

```
import torch as pt

if pt.backends.mps.is_available():
    pt_device = pt.device("mps")
    print("torch using mps")
else:
    pt_device="cpu"
    
pt.set_default_device(pt_device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `torch.set_default_device(torch.device("mps"))`.

Then use `torch.tensor()` and `torch.ones()` to create tensors on mps device (instead of using `torch.Tensor()`).

```py
import torch

print(torch.__version__)  # 2.1.0.dev20230807
device = torch.device("mps")
torch.set_default_device(device)
x = torch.tensor([0, 1])
y = torch.Tensor([2, 3])
print(x.device, y.device)  # mps:0 cpu
```